# Pisano Period length finding

Tags: math, fibonacci, number-theory

Can  0 and 1 come together in other positions of the Pisano Period except the first two positions? I am trying to solve a problem where it’s needed to know the Pisano Period length. So I was thinking about searching 0 and 1 in the period.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if 0 and 1 are adjacent, you're at a point where the sequence is repeating.

A quick proof idea: suppose that you find 0 and 1 adjacent to one another in a Fibonacci sequence mod some number n. In other words, you've found some positions k and k+1 in the sequence such that the kth position is equal to F<sub>0</sub> mod n and the (k+1)st position is equal to F<sub>1</sub> mod n. That means that position k+2 is equal to F<sub>0</sub> + F<sub>1</sub> = F<sub>2</sub> mod n, and the position after that is equal to F<sub>1</sub> + F<sub>2</sub> = F<sub>3</sub> mod n, etc. This means that if you see 0 and 1 adjacent in the sequence, what follows must be equivalent to the sequence of numbers that you'd find if you started the Fibonacci sequence again from scratch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I visualise this  say for mod 11?

Comment: Imagine addition mod 11 as a clock with only eleven hours on it. The Fibonacci sequence mod 11 can be formed by starting at 0 and 1, then iteratively moving the back point forward by the front point number of steps. If the last two points happen to be 0 and 1, then you’ll get the same sequence back as if you were starting for the first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proof idea. I was stuck with it to really understand the idea of the next 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick Python code to determine the Pisano Period

```
def pisanoPeriod(m): 
previous, current = 0, 1
for i in range(0, m * m): 
    previous, current \ 
    = current, (previous + current) % m 
      
    # A Pisano Period starts with 01 
    if (previous == 0 and current == 1): 
        return i + 1
```